# Perl regex capturing multiple instances

Tags: regex, perl

$string = "BLAH1234 xyz BALH3214 xxyyzz BALH3452"

I want to capture all instances of 4 capital letters in a row followed by 4 numbers.

I did: `$line =~ /([A-Z]{4}[0-9]{4})/g` but I can only capture the first instance. When I do $2 it says it's uninitialized.

How can I capture all instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my @matches = $string =~ /[A-Z]{4}\d{4}/g;
```

Comment: Think this might benefit from a little expansion - make clear that `g` returns a list.

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
$ echo "$tgt"
"BLAH1234 xyz BALH3214 xxyyzz BALH3452"
```

You can do:

```
$ echo "$tgt" | perl -lne 'print join("|", /[A-Z]{4}\d{4}/g)'
BLAH1234|BALH3214|BALH3452
```

Or, more explicitly:

```
my $line="BLAH1234 xyz BALH3214 xxyyzz BALH3452";
for ($line=~/[A-Z]{4}\d{4}/g) {
    print "$_\n";
}
```

A global find returns a list.